# How to automatically download .gem files, including dependencies, and save .gem's to one folder?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, download

I work behind a firewall and I need some gems to automate some processes at work.

#### Problem:

Rubygems cannot automatically download gem dependencies so I have to manually download each gem from rubygems.org and install using the local copies. As you can imagine, this could take a very long time to find each gem dependency and manually download.

#### Ideal Solution:

I would like to automatically download all of these gems on another computer not behind a firewall, package the entire collection into one folder (no need to install, just download .gem files), and make that folder available to myself to download at work. The file just needs to contain every .gem file including dependencies.

---

#### Notes:

**location:** A solution in Ruby would be ideal! Remember, I can use gems on the secondary computer to create the solution for the primary computer where I cannot download gems remotely.
**attempts:** I have poured over documentation at rubygems.org, google searched, and more, but cannot find a solution. I can't seem to access the downloaded .gem files, they are unpacked and installed before I have a chance to incercept the file and save them elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler has a great way to do this: `bundle package`.

http://bundler.io/v1.2/bundle_package.html

The package command will put all your gems in the bundle into ./vendor/cache. You can then do whatever you want with that directory, such as copying it to another machine, or checking it into version control, or  torrenting it. etc.